# Sql Server Master/Detail search query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

Customers

```
AccountId Cdescr other customer cols...
1000      ABC
```

Branch

```
AccountId BranchId Bdescr other branch cols...
1000      1        AAA
1000      2        BBB
```

I cannot find a way to achieve this

```
AccountId BranchId Cdescr Bdescr branchCols... customerCols...
1000      0        ABC    NULL   NULL          VALUES...
1000      1        NULL   AAA    VALUES...     NULL
1000      2        NULL   ABC    VALUES...     NULL
```

On the customer table missing branchId column should be set to 0 by default.

I need to be able to search for both Cdescr and Bdescr and every match on Customer table should pick up the related branches. If mathing only on the branch table anyway the related customer row should be picked up

Using a FULL OUTER JOIN joining on branchId is actually not working

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, 0 as branchId
    FROM Customers
    WHERE CONCAT(an_descr1, an_descr2) LIKE '%SEARCH_STRING%'
) a
FULL OUTER JOIN Branch d ON  d.branchId = a.branchId
```

In the current query im not able to search in the branch table

Comment: Could you please provide the query you used in order to test the full outer join? Do you receive an error or does it give a wrong result set?

Comment: From where `BranchId (0)` come?

Comment: I ve no errors... going to edit with the actual query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tCust TABLE(
AccountId INT
,Cdescr NVARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE @tBranch TABLE(
AccountId INT
,BranchId INT
,Bdescr NVARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO @tCust VALUES(1000, 'ABC');
INSERT INTO @tBranch VALUES(1000, 1, 'AAA'), (1000, 2, 'BBB');

WITH cte AS(
  SELECT ISNULL(b.AccountId, c.AccountId) AccountId, ISNULL(b.BranchId, 0) BranchId, bDescr, cDescr
    FROM @tCust c
    FULL OUTER JOIN @tBranch b ON b.AccountId = c.AccountId
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.AccountId, 0 BranchId, NULL bDescr, cDescr
    FROM @tCust c
 )
 SELECT *
   FROM cte
   WHERE CONCAT(Bdescr, Cdescr) LIKE '%ABC%'
```

Comment: How to filter in this query? For example searching for cDescr ( `WHERE cDescr LIKE '%ABC%'` ) return only 1 row

Comment: Simply by putting `WHERE Cdescr = 'ABC'` at the end of the query? However, there IS only one record with CDescr ABC, so one row should be correct... or do you expect the description to be repeated over all records?

Comment: The second one... If i search for 'ABC' i expect 3 rows.

Comment: OK, then indeed the UNION ALL should help... I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need use `UNION`.

- First query you select Customers fields with `null` value for
  `Branch` fields
- Second Query you select Branch fields with `null`
  value for `Customers` fields.

You need select explicity all the fields.
All the query need of UNION provide fields in same order and same type.

```
select
    AccountId,
    0 as BranchId,
    Customers.Cdescr,
    null as Bdescr ,
    Customers.C1,
    Customers.C2,
    null as B1,
    null as B2
from
    Customers
union all
select
    Branch.AccountId,
    Branch.BranchId,
    null Cdescr,
    Branch.Bdescr ,
    null as C1,
    null as C2,
    Branch.B1,
    Branch.B2
from
    Branch
```

Comment: You miss a space in `null asB1,` it should be `null as B1,`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `coalesce` to convert `null` to empty string:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Customers C
    FULL OUTER JOIN Branch B ON       
        C.AccountId = B.AccountId
where
    CONCAT(
      coalesce(C.an_descr1,''),
      coalesce(C.an_descr2,''),
      coalesce(B.another_descr,'')
    ) LIKE '%SEARCH_STRING%'
```